# what's the diff between resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs vs resilience4j.circuitbreaker.backends in spring application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

From my understanding `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.<baseConfigName>` defined in application.properties create new `CircuitBreakerRegistries` with custom default values

and `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.<instanceName>` create instances of `CircuitBreaker` referencing the registry defaults to use by `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.<myInstance>.base-config: <baseConfigName>`

**But** what are application.properties `resilience4j.circuitbreaker.backends.<backendName>` for??

If backends are `CircuitBreakerConfigs` how would these reference to the configs (= `CircuitBreakerRegistries`) defined?

and how would I use these backends for my CircuitBreaker instances I defined in application.properties ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`backends` was the pre `instances` configuration option and should be now considered deprecated.

> Unfortunately this breaks backward compatibility.
>   The rateLimiter used unfortunately limiters instead of backends.
>   I really don't like the name backends anyway. Maybe we should rename it to instances.
>   For backward compatibility, we could provide both options.
>   What do you think?

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/pull/460#discussion_r288423054